# withContentsofURL possible to declare a timeout limit?

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, reachability

I have an app with dynamic data and the update method uses `arrayWithContentsofURL` and `dictionaryWithContentsofURL` to get the plists from a server in order to update my database.

My problem:

When there is no or not correctly working internet connection on the device this request simply tries to get the data for about a minute before it stops trying and continues execution.

Is there a way to maybe set a timeout for this function?

PS: I know this is probably the worst way to do this and I would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction :) I'm quite new to iOS programming so please be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's best to use an [NSMutableURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with it.

Which has a `- (void)setTimeoutInterval` method. From the documentation:

> The timeout interval, in seconds. If during a connection attempt the
>   request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request
>   is considered to have timed out. The default timeout interval is 60
>   seconds.

Suggest you use an [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequest)  to send the Request object. Its delegate functions will return you the plist.

You could take [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) example, about half way on that page it downloads a json object very much the same way as you could fetch a plist.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I do understand how to set the timeout and the URL with the NSMutableURLRequest, but how could I actually get the file with this? Would you mind showing me a very basic example? I'll search the Dev Center for a code sample meanwhile

Comment: Sorry for being incomplete. I suggest you fetch the file by sending the NSMutableURLRequest over an asynchronous url connection. I'll update the my awnser.

Comment: I'll try it out.. and let you know the results.. thanks again!

Comment: sorry it took me so long :( .. I tried it out but I'm kinda stuck, will edit my answer above with the code that's not working.

Comment: uhm what I meant is that I finished editing my question, so the problem still exists :) sorry for the confusion, don't worry I'll accept the answer as soon as this works!

Comment: Could you log the response? `NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];`

Comment: it's quite big.. I'll add it on top

Comment: I think you should create a new question for this. Ask how to convert this data from this xml to an array. It's pretty easy actually but something totally different from a timeout interval.

Comment: true that.. (I hope you will answer it right away, because I have no idea =))